# Request Error in WCF service with anonymous type

Tags: wcf, json, serialization

Can a WCF service return an instance of an anonymous type or do they need to be a class? My service returns JSON for the website to consume. It would be nice to take a page from MVC and just return something like this and have the service automatically serialize it into JSON.

```
return new { user = data, lastUpdate = time, success = true };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't *ever* return an object of an anonymous type from *any* method. Not and have much useful happen with it.

The problem is not specific to WCF. It just gets *worse* in WCF since WCF has to worry about generating metadata from your service contract. Remember that the service contract isn't the part that decides to return JSON, so WCF can't do anything special for this particular method.

Comment: Yup makes sense to me. Thanks!